# Flutter: how get device screen DPI value

Tags: flutter, screen, dpi

Is there a way to get the actual value of screen DPI in Flutter (Dart)??

I need that value to calculate many other stuffs, and so it's not enought for me to use integrated Flutter features about responsiveness.

I really need a **raw DPI value**. (I mean for example like: `MediaQuery.of(context).dpi` //but it doesn't exits ).

Thank you so much

Comment: Take a look at https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil

Comment: https://github.com/iampawan/myportfolio/blob/master/lib/responsive_widget.dart check it out